# How to I best set file permissions in a home network with Windows Computers?

Tags: windows, networking, permissions, home-networking

How to I set up file permissions in a home network with Windows computers?

1. Need both read and modify
2. Windows 7-8.1
3. The most important files are on a USB drive connected to a Windows 7 netbook "server".
4. Mix of live id and regular accounts
5. Most users "comes from" a specific account on a specific computer most of the time.

Comment: Ugh... This kind of setup is notoriously hard to find an easy solution... I often have small businesses try to do this to "cut costs" and it always ends in tears. The problem you have is that each computer has an account and adding these accounts to your shared folders needs you to know the machine name with the local account to add. You could create a HomeGroup but I don't know how you'll, again, manage permissions per user...

Comment: What do you do if you don't "cut costs"?  Doesn't live id help?  Also, isn't it simpler if I use a group?

Comment: If you don't cut costs you run a small domain either using a Microsoft server solution or you can create a "near enough" with a Linux server - both created as a Domain Controller. A central place to manage use accounts and shares. You can't, however, join your normal "Home Premium" versions to a domain - this is normally for an office environment. The HomeGroup, unfortunately, allows you to share resources to everyone on your network or no-one. But home networks are designed that everything is shared..